# Which Switches Faster? Transistor, Solid-State Relay or Relay

Tags: transistors, relay, solid-state-relay, switching, mechanical

Which Switching Device can Switch from Off to On and Off the fastest?

1. Transistor
2. Solid State Relay
3. or Mechanical Relay

Comment: What's the purpose of the switch?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: what do you think is likely to switch faster? A lump of metal or charge carriers in a piece of semiconductor?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Im trying to find what device is most suitable for quick changes in the power

Comment: @Icy what about the difference between solid state relays and transistor?

Comment: @Bryan "quick changes in the power" - what does this mean? What are you trying to do or understand?

Comment: @Andyaka i mean turning on and off quickly.

Comment: Solid state relays are semiconductor devices that will switch AC - they are typically implemented using TRIACS - which will only switch the circuit off when the AC voltage passes zero. Some may implement switching on at zero crossing points only as well. So may be slower at switching low frequency mains than mechanical relays - but you will need to check specific devices data sheets for exact characteristics.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is a simple question, true, but AFAICS it meets the generate criteria for SE postings, ie. short, specific, answerable.

Comment: The research I expect with such a question would be to look up the switching speeds of some example devices, then purpose an answer. The answering responses would be yes/no and an explanation of why / why not and then possibly those little exceptions to the norm that catch out the first time users of such devices. So the down vote was for zero research and the speed of switching is not stated! Fast is not a quantity any one can quantify..so is switching at once an hour acceptable?

Comment: Ok . Which is fastest? was the question... but why do you need to know this?. I ask because this affects which is most suitable (this can be cheapest, most applicable,simplest or most robust) for you application and absolute switching speed (in cycles per second =Hz) in the GHz is not needed for 99% of most applications.

Comment: Reads like a homework question...

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it is NOT specific. Without any details about the amount of voltage or current you want to switch, it's far too broad. Also, "the fastest" is far too vague -- are you talking about the speed of a single transition, or the overall repetition rate? If you gave us some context about what you're actually trying to accomplish, we'd be able to provide specific advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transistors are used in extremely high frequency radio amplifiers and transmitters (we're talking frequencies that are many GHz). They are also used in very high speed devices such as CPUs, FPGAs, logic devices and the list of high speed devices goes on and on.

Solid state relays are quite often used to turn on and off an appliance connected to a 50 or 60 Hz power AC supply as are mechanical relays. However mechanical relays need to physically move an armature to perform a switching action.

Based on what I've said, what do you think is the fastest device.

Answer (score -1):

Speed of switching vs Component.

`Time       0-------------------------------------------------Eternity (~25mS)`

---

Transistor |*****
SSR        |******* 
Relay      |***************************************************************>>

Capiche?